# Marshalled C string missing character

Tags: c#, marshalling

I am having a problem with marshalling a C character array. I have the following C# structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 16, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi), Serializable]
internal struct Header
{
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4)]
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public string header;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public int version;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public int diroffset;

    [FieldOffset(12)]
    public int direntries;
}
```

and the following code to read this structure from a stream:

```
public static T ReadStruct<T>(this Stream stream) where T : struct
{
    var sz = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
    var buffer = new byte[sz];
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, sz);

    var pinnedBuffer = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);

    var structure = (T) Marshal.PtrToStructure(
        pinnedBuffer.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));

    pinnedBuffer.Free();
    return structure;
}
```

Now my problem is that the `header` field misses a character after the struct is read. The file where the struct is read from contains the four bytes `VPVP` but after the struct has been read by `ReadStruct` the header string only contains `VPV`. If I take a look at the byte array in the read function in the debugger then that array contains the values 86, 80, 86, 80 which is `VPVP`. I also tried using `LayoutKind.Sequential` for the `StructLayout` but that didn't change anything.

Am I doing something wrong or why is there a character missing in my string?

Comment: The last byte might be occupied by the null string terminator. Maybe try setting the `SizeConst` to 5? Just guessing.

Comment: Memo for others:
I think someone misused char[4] instead uint32 (for example: const uint32_t png_ihdr = 'IHDR';) for debuging purposes to read in debug string while this is actually uint32. You should be using uint32 for value and for constants for comparations (it's also faster to use uint32 if you have a lot of tags to parse and compare).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're having lies in the struct definition, not in writing the bytes to it.

The problem lies right here:

```
[MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4)]
```

As you've stated, you're writing out the text `VPVP`, which is 4 characters long, you'd think. This, however, is not the case. In C, you could declare the string as such:

```
char mystring[] = { 'V', 'P', 'V', 'P', '\0' };
```

You need that null character (`\0`) at the end, to mark off the end of the string. You need to take this into account when marshalling, because you need to reserve space for that "null terminator byte", if you do not, the C# string will add it for you in the available memory, so it will eat away your last character. So if you're gonna use a null-terminated string, you will have to make it of length 5.

---

**EDIT:** Here is a better solution, where you don't have to worry about null-terminators, you just use a `char[]` (and you also keep the magic 16 byte size):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 16, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi), Serializable]
internal struct Header
{
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    private char[] headerCharArray;

    public string header
    {
        get { return new string(headerCharArray); }
        set
        {
            if (value.Length == 4)
            {
                headerCharArray = value.ToArray();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("String length was not 4.");
            }
        }
    }

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public int version;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public int diroffset;

    [FieldOffset(12)]
    public int direntries;
}
```

That way the `char[]` is stored in memory, and you can access it as a string through the property, which doesn't take in any memory of the struct itself.

Comment: The problem is that the string is not the typical string, it's just a four byte char array. The C-definition looks like this `char id[4];` (plus the other fields).

Comment: @asarium I just thought of that as well, will update the answer if I think of the 'proper' solutiuon.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! I only needed the character array itself so I didn't need the string property.